# Data don't display when deploy

Tags: node.js, mongodb

everyone!

I'm using Node.js in the back-end.

Deploy: Back-end:Heroku, Front-end: Netlify, database:MongoDB

my back-end deploys perfectly but doesn't show any data. just the Cannot GET /

here a $ heroku logs --tail

```
2021-10-23T16:05:14.000000+00:00 app[api]: Build started by user federico.acosta045@gmail.com
2021-10-23T16:05:34.468041+00:00 app[api]: Release v29 created by user federico.acosta045@gmail.com
2021-10-23T16:05:34.468041+00:00 app[api]: Deploy 964d7738 by user federico.acosta045@gmail.com
2021-10-23T16:05:34.692911+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Restarting2021-10-23T16:05:34.719884+00:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from up to starting
2021-10-23T16:05:35.000000+00:00 app[api]: Build succeeded2021-10-23T16:05:35.442730+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Stopping all processes with SIGTERM
2021-10-23T16:05:35.628361+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Process exited with status 143
2021-10-23T16:05:36.730785+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Starting process with command `PORT=48834 node ./index.js`
2021-10-23T16:05:37.855134+00:00 app[web.1]: Connected to 
MongoDB
2021-10-23T16:05:37.857337+00:00 app[web.1]: Server is listening on port 48834...
2021-10-23T16:05:38.397965+00:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from starting to up
2021-10-23T16:06:30.122049+00:00 heroku[router]: at=info method=GET path="/" host=bloghiv-back.herokuapp.com request_id=8915e3c2-cd38-45e5-99a8-23d7baad4d81 fwd="200.126.224.126" dyno=web.1 connect=0ms service=8ms status=404 bytes=383 protocol=https
```

here's my SERVER index.js

```
const express = require("express");
const app = express();

const mongoose = require("mongoose");
const authRoute = require("./routes/auth");
const userRoute = require("./routes/users");
const postRoute = require("./routes/posts");
const categoryRoute = require("./routes/categories");
const multer = require("multer");
const path = require("path");
require('dotenv').config();

app.use(express.json());
app.use("/images", express.static(path.join(__dirname, "/images")));



mongoose
  .connect('mongodb+srv://fedexx45:4635223TWIfe@cluster0.t3yny.mongodb.net/API-blog?retryWrites=true&w=majority', {
    useNewUrlParser: true,
    useUnifiedTopology: true,
    useCreateIndex: true, // just a recomended line if there's an error
    useFindAndModify:true
  })
  .then(console.log("Connected to MongoDB"))
  .catch((err) => console.log(err));

const storage = multer.diskStorage({
  destination: (req, file, cb) => {
    cb(null, "images");
  },
  filename: (req, file, cb) => {
    cb(null, req.body.name);
  },
});

const upload = multer({ storage: storage });

app.post("/api/upload", upload.single("file"), (req, res) => {
  res.status(200).json("File has been uploaded");
});

app.use("/api/auth", authRoute);
app.use("/api/users", userRoute);
app.use("/api/posts", postRoute);
app.use("/api/categories", categoryRoute);

const PORT = process.env.PORT || 80;

app.listen(PORT, () => console.log(`Server is listening on port ${PORT}...`));
const express = require("express");
const app = express();

const mongoose = require("mongoose");
const authRoute = require("./routes/auth");
const userRoute = require("./routes/users");
const postRoute = require("./routes/posts");
const categoryRoute = require("./routes/categories");
const multer = require("multer");
const path = require("path");
require('dotenv').config();

app.use(express.json());
app.use("/images", express.static(path.join(__dirname, "/images")));



mongoose
  .connect('mongodb+srv://api-info', {
    useNewUrlParser: true,
    useUnifiedTopology: true,
    useCreateIndex: true, // just a recomended line if there's an error
    useFindAndModify:true
  })
  .then(console.log("Connected to MongoDB"))
  .catch((err) => console.log(err));

const storage = multer.diskStorage({
  destination: (req, file, cb) => {
    cb(null, "images");
  },
  filename: (req, file, cb) => {
    cb(null, req.body.name);
  },
});

const upload = multer({ storage: storage });

app.post("/api/upload", upload.single("file"), (req, res) => {
  res.status(200).json("File has been uploaded");
});

app.use("/api/auth", authRoute);
app.use("/api/users", userRoute);
app.use("/api/posts", postRoute);
app.use("/api/categories", categoryRoute);

const PORT = process.env.PORT || 80;

app.listen(PORT, () => console.log(`Server is listening on port ${PORT}...`));
```

(in order to make it work I put my MONGO_URL in my index directly)
as well I'm using a .env file to store MONGO_URL and
PORT= 5000 node index.js

I don't know what's the problem exactly... but I can offer more info I u want

Answer (score 0):

You don't have a route defined for `GET /`:

Add this before `app.post("/api/upload....` :

```
app.get("/", (req, res) => {
  res.status(200).json({
    status: 'ok',
    message: 'Hello! I am the root!'
  });
});
```

This log line `2021-10-23T16:06:30.122049+00:00 heroku[router]: at=info method=GET path="/" host=bl.....` says you have requested `https://your-hostname.heroku/` via `GET` method, but there is no route defined so you need to add the code above.

Comment: oh!! thank you soo much! I been struggling with this for 2 days!

Comment: Good! So, please accept the answer :)

Comment: so now I have to define a route for each section of the page? like /register /login?

Comment: you need to define routes for every endpoint you want to be reached. So, if you need a /login page, you had to define a route for GET /login and so on...